# Linux/Windows dual boot, linux no longer can see disk windows is on

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub

I can no longer dual boot my ubuntu/windows laptop! I have 3 physical drives on my laptop: a 1TB drive with Linux OSs (EXT4) and storage partition (EXT4) , a 256GB drive with windows (NTFS), and a 1TB drive for basically steam games when on my windows (xFAT). For many months, my dual booting worked fine: I'd get GRUB to give me the option to boot into ubuntu or windows. All of a sudden, GRUB stopped giving me that option. There might have been a windows update around that time but I'm not sure.

```
$ fdisk -l /dev/sd*
Disk /dev/sda: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 860 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 18E98FBB-1792-4B9F-AE70-D7230CF76A40

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        4096     618495     614400   300M EFI System
/dev/sda2      618496  390405605  389787110 185.9G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  1917749445 1953520064   35770620  17.1G Linux swap
/dev/sda4   390406144 1722437631 1332031488 635.2G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda5  1722437632 1917749247  195311616  93.1G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/sda1: 300 MiB, 314572800 bytes, 614400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/sda2: 185.89 GiB, 199571000320 bytes, 389787110 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda3: 17.6 GiB, 18314557440 bytes, 35770620 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda4: 635.17 GiB, 682000121856 bytes, 1332031488 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda5: 93.14 GiB, 99999547392 bytes, 195311616 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

is what pops out of fdisk (I abbreviated the output because snap creates a crap ton of /dev/loop* for whatever reason.

The BIOS sees the ubuntu partition and windows partition. When I boot into windows, I go straight to windows; when I boot into ubuntu, I get GRUB with only ubuntu options. GParted in ubuntu sees the disk with linux on it and that's it. Windows disk management sees all 3 disks.

fstab gives

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=89fd39a1-00ee-429d-9180-ee01e4b902cb /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=AEE5-58FE  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=df732c5a-28b7-4602-8e1b-0028a0680d9c none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/28610f4e-5241-482f-88cc-bdbad16b5c9b /mnt/Storage auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Anyone have any idea about what could be causing this? I don't immediately think failed drive because both the SSD and nvme that are the 256GB windows disk and the 1TB steam game storage disk would be failing simultaneously maybe?

Comment: Windows updates may have turned Window fast startup back on. That sets hibernation flag preventing the Linux NTFS driver from fully seeing the NTFS partitions & grub from booting Windows. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to oldfred's suggestion, one part of the problem was Windows fast startup being on. In addition, my BIOS was using Intel's RST, and that had to be turned off too before I could get Ubuntu/GRUB to see the other disks!